# UserRole ID in VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, roles, id, global-variables

Writing a VisualForce Page for Opportunity and having an issue with referencing the `$UserRole.Id`. It saves the way its written but its not doing what we need it to on the actual VisualForce Page. It is working for the `$UserRole.Name` tho :/ .

The code is as follows-

```
<apex:page Controller="CloseOppController">
  <apex:form>
    <apex:pageBlock title="Opportunity Close Form">
    <apex:pageMessages />
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Win/Loss Detail" collapsible="false">
      <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.StageName}" required="true"/>
      <br/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Closed_Reason__c}" required="{!IF($UserRole.Name != 'Sales Ops', true, false)}"/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Reason_Code__c}" required="{!IF($UserRole.Name != '***I have tried both the 15 digit and the 18 digit ID HERE***', true, false)}"/>
      <br/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Primary_Competitor__c}" required="{!IF($UserRole.Name != 'Sales Ops',true,false)}"/>
      <br/>
      <apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.Additional_Competitors__c}"/>
      <br/>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: UserRole.Name is generally not an id. Have you tried querying the UserRole object through the workbench or dev console etc?

I have also cleaned up your post a bit. In the future try and format your questions so they are easily read. :)

Comment: Just fyi `IF(boolean_expression, true, false)` is always identical to simply `boolean_expression`. In other words, it is excessively verbose.

Comment: @JesseMilburn Sorry for the confusion... Yes, I am aware that UserRole.Name is not an ID... but the User's Role has an ID associated with it. ID is what I am trying to use instead of Name because we're more likely to change the "name" than the ID of the Role.
When I use the UserRole.Name it does work and the field is not required for our Sales Ops folks... when I use the 15 or 18 digit ID of the "Sales Ops" Role it Saves but it doesnt work for either. This is the problem I am trying to solve. We want to use the ID instead of the Name... what am I doing wrong in the code that is not letting me?

Comment: @AdrianLarson , Can you please explain... I feel like there were some key words missing because I did not understand your statement?

Comment: I'm not sure I can state it more simply... you are evaluating a truthy expression and then saying if it is true, use true, and if it is false, use false. Just use the truthy value.

Comment: Also, can you update with correct syntax?

Comment: @AdrianLarson Gotcha... thats the same thing my boy over atFF was suggesting I fix later... I figure ill tackle that once I get the whole thing working.
What specifically are you looking to have updated... I copy and pasted the first half of the code... the only difference is instead of showing you our Role ID I put the words I have tried the 15 and 18 digit Ids here? Do you need the second half of the code?

Comment: Your `<>` inequality operator was disappearing. I changed it to `!=` and it is now displaying valid syntax.

Comment: Why not try `$UserRole.Id != [whitelisted value]`?

Comment: I am familiar with IP Address WhiteListing... this isn't an IP address tho... can you explain a further please?

Comment: Is there something you do not understand about the fact that `{!IF($UserRole.Name != AN ID`} will always evaluate to true as a UserRole Name is NEVER an ID value? There are a lot of comments here yet I think we are still at the same issue?